# Jenkins docker.image().withRun() what host name do I use to connect

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline and I'm trying to run a Postgres container and connect to it for some nodejs integrations tests. My Jenkins file looks like this:

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
      script {
        docker.image('postgres:10.5-alpine').withRun('-e "POSTGRES_USER=fred" -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD="foobar" -e "POSTGRES_DB=mydb" -p 5432:5432') { c->
        sh 'npm run test'  
    }
  }
}
```

What hostname should I use to connect to the postgres database inside of my nodejs code? I have tried localhost but I get a connection refused exception:

```
ERROR=Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
ERROR:Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

Additional Details:
I've added a sleep for 30 seconds for the container to start up. I know there are better ways to do this but for now I just want to solve the connection problem.

I run docker logs on the container to see if it is ready to accept connections, and it is.

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
      script {
        docker.image('postgres:10.5-alpine').withRun('-e "POSTGRES_USER=fred" -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD="foobar" -e "POSTGRES_DB=mydb" -p 5432:5432') { c->
        sleep 60
        sh "docker logs ${c.id}"
        sh 'npm run test'       
    }
  }
}
```

tail of docker logs command:

```
2019-09-02 12:30:37.729 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I am running Jenkins itself in a docker container, so I am wondering if this is a factor?

My goal is to have a database startup with empty tables, run my integration tests against it, then shut down the database. 
I can't run my tests inside of the container because the code I'm testing lives outside the container and triggered the jenkins pipeline to begin with. This is part of a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline and it's triggered by a push to a feature branch.

Comment: is your nodejs application running inside container?

Comment: No, I want my nodejs application to run outside the container, similar to how I would test outside of jenkins (stand up a db using docker and point to it). Does it have to run inside the container?

Comment: are you sure that your container is running ? `docker ps`

Comment: ...and are you sure it's started up and accepting connections?  There's not a pure-Docker way to check this, but Docker database containers can take a minute or so to actually start up.

Answer (score 0):

your code sample is missing a closing curly bracket and has an excess / mismatched quote. That way it is not clear whether you actually did (or wanted to) run your `sh` commands, inside or outside the call.

Depending on where the closing bracket was, the container might already have shut down.

Generally, the Postgres connection is fine with that fixed syntax issues:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.image('postgres:10.5-alpine')
                    .withRun('-e "POSTGRES_USER=fred" '+
                        '-e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foobar" '+
                        '-e "POSTGRES_DB=mydb" '+
                        '-p 5432:5432'
                    ){
                        sh script: """
                            sleep 5
                            pg_isready -h localhost
                        """
                        //sh 'npm run test'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

> pg_isready -h localhost
> localhost:5432 - accepting connections